# Coloring by principal component loading

Tags: data-visualization, pca

In a diagram, I would like to indicate an item's principal component loadings by color. The idea is to map the item's loadings on three principal components (e.g., the first three) onto RGB values.

The items in question can be represented by 20-dimensional unit vectors (in the specific case motivating this question, the items are protein sequences and I am analyzing their amino-acid composition). The principal components are derived from eigendecomposition of the correlation matrix of these vectors for a large number of items.

One can envision simple mappings like: eigenvectors = $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{T}$, target $n \times 1$ vector = $\mathbf{v}$, projection $\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{v}'\mathbf{T}$, first three loadings of projection $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{p_{i \in 1\dots 3}}$, and a vector of RGB values between 0 and 1 obtained from $(\mathbf{n/||n||}+[1\quad1\quad1]')/2$ (which first normalizes $\mathbf{n}$, yielding entries guaranteed to lie in [-1,1], and then maps [-1,1] entries to [0,1] entries).

This is pretty simple and seems to work, but may have non-obvious blindspots; I am particularly worried about whether the simple normalizations lead to poor coverage of color space and thus poor contrast. A major goal, as with all color-coding, is to provide visual contrast.

Is there a standard solution to this problem? If not, suggestions to improve this one?

Updated: the intended application is to allow automatic and informative coloring of items outside of a scatterplot or other quantitative format. An [example](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v7/n7/images/nrm1963-f3.jpg) of such a format is shown below; each row is a protein sequence, and each colored cylinder is a region of the protein sharing certain characteristics, with the same color used to indicate repeated instances of a type of region. The limitation is that the similarities or differences in colors, in this example, have no meaning and are chosen for graphical design reasons.

[image: Fig. 3 from Schreiber et al. 2006]

Comment: I like your idea, it sounds interesting. I don't think I have ever seen anything like that, this is definitely not a standard approach. Can you maybe show one of your figures, for the benefit of the community? In particular, it is not clear what sort of diagram you want to colour this way; e.g. to make a scatter plot of your 20d data, you need to project it on a plane first, and if you use first two PCs for that, then colouring becomes redundant. So I guess it is not a scatter plot, but what then?

Comment: Have you tried to experiment with a couple of other colour models? Eg. HSV was specifically designed to be more intuitive that RGB in terms of colour vision.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and easy to incorporate -- any 3D color model can be mapped.

Comment: I would be cautious of trying to use any colour model to map three different variables -- there's just too much interaction in the perceived value of the colour.  (E.g., at low saturation or extremes of value hue becomes indistinguishable).  That said, you can probably successfully map *two* variables to colour, either using two dimensions of hue, fully saturated (like the [YCbCr colour plane at Y=0.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr)), or using one dimension of hue between two primary colours and one dimension of brightness.